# Woocommerce related products by its category or rank math primary category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to use the Rank Math Primary Category option to display related products in WooCommerce.

I've pretty got this sorted using this code:

```
/* Rank Math SEO - Use Primary Category for Related Products */
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {

    // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
    $primary_cat_id   = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
    $primary_cat_info = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, 'product_cat' );
    $primary_cat_slug = $primary_cat_info->slug;

    // Get ids of just the posts in this category. We only want related posts from the primary category.
    $args = array(
        'status'            => 'publish',
        'category'          => array( $primary_cat_slug ),
        'return'            => 'ids',
        'exclude'           => array( $product_id ),
        'visibility'        => 'catalog',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    );
    $related_posts = wc_get_products( $args );

    return $related_posts;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
```

The problem is if a product only belongs to a single category, it doesn't have a primary category... so therefore doesn't display any related products.

Is there a way I can add some extra code that will show related products by the category a product is in, if it's only in one category... and if it's in more than one category the Rank Math Primary Category will be used?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to count the product categories that are set in the product.

Try the following:

```php
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat';
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); // Get product categories

    // Check if the product has more than one product category
    if( count( $categories ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id   = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $primary_cat_info = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy );

        // Get ids of just the posts in this category. We only want related posts from the primary category.
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => array( $primary_cat_info->slug ),
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
```

It should work now.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, thank you for so much for your help :) This works perfectly! Is there a way to use the subcategory for related products if only one category is selected? I've tried using the code found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131383/display-related-products-based-on-subcategory-woocommerce but I think it might be outdated as it doesn't seem to do anything, and I haven't been able to find a more recent alternative.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, sorry about that! I thought I'd seen other questions with multiple answers and updates. Thank you for you help :) Should I ask about the related posts by subcategory as a seperate question? Do you perhaps know of a more recent answer that I can try and impliment into the code you've provided, so I'm not asking an existing questions? Thanks again, very much appreciated!

Comment: The mentioned answer is old and not accepted, so ask a new question. In that new question you can add a link to the old thread, saying that it's outdated and doesn't work. And better, if you tried something, provide that code even if it doesn't work. Always try to provide your own code attempts. once done notify me here, if you like.