# WooCommerce Related Products by children category as fallback to Rank Math Primary Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76938712/woocommerce-related-products-by-subcategory-or-rank-math-primary-category) applied, to show WooCommerce Related Products by the Rank Math Primary Category, when 2 or more categories are selected in the product.

```
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat';
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); // Get product categories

    // Check if the product has more than one product category
    if( count( $categories ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id   = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $primary_cat_info = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy );

        // Get ids of just the posts in this category. We only want related posts from the primary category.
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => array( $primary_cat_info->slug ),
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
```

I'm trying to include a fallback for products that have only a single category selected (standard or Primary), to use their subcategory for displaying related products.

I've tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131383/display-related-products-based-on-subcategory-woocommerce) on its own as a test, but it seems out of date and doesn't display products from the subcategory.

Furthermore, I also tried overwriting the WooCommerce related.php template file as suggested in the same question.
This worked, but stopped the Rank Math Primary Category code above from working.

I haven't been able to work out how to use parts of the template overwrite in the Rank Math Primary Category code.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the related products from children categories (subcategories) as fallback, when there is only one product category set in the product, try the following revisited code:

```php
// Rank Math SEO - Use Primary Category for Related Products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $category_ids = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); 
    $term_slugs   = array(); // Initializing   

    if( count($category_ids) == 1 ) {
        // Get children categories
        $children_ids = get_term_children( reset($category_ids), $taxonomy );
        // Loop through children terms Ids
        foreach ( $children_ids as $tem_id ) {
            $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $tem_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from each term Id
        }
    } 
    elseif( count( $category_ids ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $term_slugs[]   = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from the term Id
    }

    if ( count($term_slugs) > 0 ) {
        // Product query: Get product Ids
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => $term_slugs,
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
```

It should work as expected.

---

When there is only one product category, if you want to merge the children terms IDs with that current product category, replace in the code:

```php
foreach ( $children_ids as $tem_id ) {
```

with

```php
foreach ( array_merge( $category_ids, $children_ids ) as $tem_id ) {
```

---

Addition

As demanded by the OP in the comments *(separate parts)*:

```php
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $category_ids = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); 

    // If there is only one product category
    if( count($category_ids) == 1 ) {
        $term_slugs   = array(); // Initializing  
        // Get children categories
        $children_ids = get_term_children( reset($category_ids), $taxonomy );
        // Loop through children terms Ids
        foreach ( array_merge( $category_ids, $children_ids ) as $tem_id ) {
            $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $tem_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from each term Id
        }
         // Product query: Get product Ids
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => $term_slugs,
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    } 

    // If the product has more than one product category
    if( count( $category_ids ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id   = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $primary_cat_info = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy );

        // Get ids of just the posts in this category. We only want related posts from the primary category.
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => array( $primary_cat_info->slug ),
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
```

It should also work the same way.

Comment: Thank you LoicTheAztec, this works perfectly! I had th add the 'foreach ( array_merge( $category_ids, $children_ids ) as $tem_id ) {' part for it to work in all areas, so thank you very much for the additional detail too :)

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, are you able to post how I might just use the Related Products by subcategory part on its own please? I'm trying to work it out but keep getting errors... this is really just so I can see how it works, though I'm sure others might find it very helpful with the only other answer being so old... and incorrect.

Comment: I added an addition.