# Use custom taxonomy to select Related Products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a woocommerce store with the two standard taxonomies - "categories" and "tags" - and a custom taxonomy "sport." I have used the following code to focus Related Products on the "primary" category. ( Taken from this post:  [WooCommerce Related Products by children category as fallback to Rank Math Primary Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942086/woocommerce-related-products-by-children-category-as-fallback-to-rank-math-prima?noredirect=1&lq=1) )

Now what I would like to do is to pick products that share the "custom taxonomy" "sport" rather than a "category."

Is there a simple way to adapt this code to "sport" rather than "category" to select Related Products?

Thanks.

```
// Rank Math SEO - Use Primary Category for Related Products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
    $category_ids = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); 
    $term_slugs   = array(); // Initializing   

    if( count($category_ids) == 1 ) {
        // Get children categories
        $children_ids = get_term_children( reset($category_ids), $taxonomy );
        // Loop through children terms Ids
        foreach ( $children_ids as $tem_id ) {
            $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $tem_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from each term Id
        }
    } 
    elseif( count( $category_ids ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $term_slugs[]   = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from the term Id
    }

    if ( count($term_slugs) > 0 ) {
        // Product query: Get product Ids
        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'category'      => $term_slugs,
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
```

I tried replacing taxonomy='product_cat' with taxonomy='sport'

That led the function to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the filter with the following changes, replacing the use of the 'product_cat' taxonomy with the custom 'sport' taxonomy and adjusting the logic for obtaining the term information.

Sample:

```php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_esporte_taxonomy', 10, 3 );
    function related_products_from_esporte_taxonomy( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
        $taxonomy     = 'sport'; 
        $term_ids     = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); 
        $term_slugs   = array(); 
    
        if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
                $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy )->slug; 
    
                // Gets the IDs of child terms
                $children_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
    
                foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
                    $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $child_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // Gets the slug of each child term
                }
            }
    
            $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
                'status'        => 'publish',
                'tax_query'     => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term_slugs,
                    ),
                ),
                'return'        => 'ids',
                'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
                'visibility'    => 'catalog',
                'limit'         => -1,
            ) );
        }
    
        return $related_posts;
    }
```

Instead of checking categories and their subcategories, you can directly retrieve the terms from the custom taxonomy "sport". The method `get_term_children` fetches the child terms of the taxonomy for each parent term found in the products. Also, adjust the product query to include a `tax_query` that searches for products having the selected terms in the custom taxonomy "esporte".

You can also debug the code to analyze the responses more effectively in WordPress.

Open the wp-config.php file.
And insert the following code into the file:

```php
    // Enable debug mode
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    // Store logs in /wp-content/debug.log
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

In the above code, in addition to enabling debugging, all encountered errors are also stored in a log file. The file is located at `wp-content/debug.log`.

If you are working on a live installation, or your code is reporting a lot of bugs, you should also set the following to false in your `wp-config.php` file,

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

this will switch off the error logging on the front-end and only log them in the `debug.log` file.

Comment: Thank you @ramonsoarez. This answer worked to select products from the sport taxonomy. It chooses items that are in a common child term. I would like it to select items also from a sub-child term. I have posted that as a new question.