# Select a woocommerce Related Product based on custom taxonomy with 3 levels in the hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a woocommerce store with a custom taxonomy "sport." The taxonomy has three levels - Parent, Child, Sub-Child - for example: Indoor Sport > Arena Sport > Basketball. If a user views a basketball item, then I want Related Products to prioritize showing other basketball items, and then fallback to Arena Sport items if there are not enough basketball items. So, first check the most junior level - Sub-Child, then Child, then Parent.

Additionally, I use RankMath, and can set a taxonomy term as the "Primary" term. So, in the example above, the primary term would be basketball. The Primary term will almost always be a sub-child term, but could be a Child term.

I have combined responses from two other questions, and the code works in that it chooses Related Products from the sport taxonomy. But it only looks at the child level, not at the sub-child level. So, in the example above, it selects items that are within Arena Sports without prioritizing Basketball.

What changes should I make to ensure that Related Products sees the "Primary" taxonomy term and then looks for products with that term first, and then, if necessary, looks in the next level up the hierarchy of terms?

Grateful for any help or suggestions you can offer.

I referred to these two posts in drafting my code:

[WooCommerce Related Products by children category as fallback to Rank Math Primary Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942086/woocommerce-related-products-by-children-category-as-fallback-to-rank-math-prima?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Use custom taxonomy to select Related Products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949696/use-custom-taxonomy-to-select-related-products-in-woocommerce/76956395#76956395)

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rankmath_primary_esporte_taxonomy', 10, 3 );
    function related_products_from_rankmath_primary_esporte_taxonomy( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
        $taxonomy     = 'sport'; 
        $term_ids     = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); 
        $term_slugs   = array(); 
  
 if( count($term_ids) == 1 ) {
        // Get children categories
        $children_ids = get_term_children( reset($category_ids), $taxonomy );
        // Loop through children terms Ids
        foreach ( $children_ids as $tem_id ) {
            $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $tem_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from each term Id
        }
    } 
    elseif( count( $term_ids ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary taxonomy/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_tax_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_taxonomy', true );
        $term_slugs[]   = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_tax_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from the term Id
    }
        
        
        if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
                $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy )->slug; 
    
                // Gets the IDs of child terms
                $children_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
    
                foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
                    $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $child_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // Gets the slug of each child term
                }
            }
   
   
            $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
                'status'        => 'publish',
                'tax_query'     => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term_slugs,
                    ),
                ),
                'return'        => 'ids',
                'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
                'visibility'    => 'catalog',
                'limit'         => -1,
            ) );
        }

    
    
        return $related_posts;
    }
```

Comment: *"if there are not enough basketball items…"* How much is "not enough" (try to be very explicit)? Review your question, to make it as clear as possible. And kindly, please remove "thank you", as nobody has helped you yet.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. I am currently displaying six (6) items in the Related Products section. Thus if there were only two basketball items, I would need to get four additional items from the more senior levels - Arena Sports and Indoor Sports.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (commented):

```php
// Utility function: Get related product Ids with a custom tax query
function get_related_posts_custom_query( $term_slugs, $taxonomy, $product_id ) {
    return wc_get_products( array(
        'limit'         => -1,
        'status'        => 'publish',
        'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
        'visibility'    => 'catalog',
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term_slugs,
            ),
        ),
        'return'        => 'ids',
    ) );
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category', 10, 3 );
function related_products_from_rank_math_primary_category( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ) {
    // Get product categories set for the product
    $category_ids = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') ); 
    $term_slugs   = array(); // Initializing   

    // 1). Only one product category => Fallback (Query products from "Sport" taxonomy)
    if( count($category_ids) == 1 ) {
        $taxonomy      = 'sport';
        // Get "Sport" the term set in the product
        $sport_ids     = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids') ); 
        $term          = get_term_by( 'id', reset($sport_ids), $taxonomy );
        $term_slugs[]  = $term ->slug;
        // Get related products from the "Sport" term
        $related_posts = get_related_posts_custom_query( $term_slugs, $taxonomy, $product_id );

        // IF there is not enough related products: Add the CHILDREN terms
        if ( $related_posts < 6 ) {
            $children_ids = get_term_children( reset($sport_ids), $taxonomy );
            if( count($children_ids) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $children_ids as $tem_id ) {
                    $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $tem_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from each term Id
                }
                // Get related products from the "Sport" terms
                $related_posts = get_related_posts_custom_query( $term_slugs, $taxonomy, $product_id );
            }
            // IF there is not enough related products: Add the PARENT term
            if ( $related_posts < 6 ) {
                $parent       = get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, $taxonomy );
                $term_slugs[] = $parent ->slug;
                // Get related products from the "Sport" terms
                return get_related_posts_custom_query( $term_slugs, $taxonomy, $product_id );
            } else {
                return $related_posts;
            }
        } else {
            return $related_posts;
        }
    } 
    // 2). More than one product categories => Rank Math SEO
    elseif( count( $category_ids ) > 1 ) {
        // Get the primary category/term as saved by Rank Math SEO
        $primary_cat_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'rank_math_primary_product_cat', true );
        $taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
        $term_slugs[]   = get_term_by( 'id', $primary_cat_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // get the slug from the term Id
        // Get related products from the category terms via Rank Math SEO
        return get_related_posts_custom_query( $term_slugs, $taxonomy, $product_id );
    }
    return $related_posts;
}
```

it should work.